# h:outputText rendered to assignValue

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 5.1, When outputText rendered to I need assign value more Filed?

```
<p:outputPanel>
<h:outputText id="StatusId" value="#{student.Status}"
rendered="#{student.statusFieldsRendered}">
<f:setPropertyActionListener  value="#{common.rightHeader}"  
target="#{student.addMoreField}"/>
</h:outputText>
</p:outputPanel>
```

I try above f:setPropertyActionListener to be error then any other to assign value when ouputText  to rendered

Comment: Why what is the usecase? Very uncommon question

Comment: when th outputText rendered true to assign rightHeader to addMoreField

Comment: That was already clear from the question. But why? The full non-technical usecase please

Comment: Controller logic doesn't belong in view. You're only making it harder for yourself this way. Just do it at exactly the moment the `statusFieldsRendered` property is changed to `true` in some action listener method.